# Symfony 6 - Many to Many Relationship - Storage of Data in Linking Table?

Tags: mysql, symfony, many-to-many, entity

I am currently working on a symfony 6 project with a mysql database and have the following issue:

**My situation:**
I have two tables/entities:

1. Orders
2. Article

This two entities are related in a many to many relationship. So one order can have many articles and one article can belong to many orders.

This relationship leads to the creation of a third table that links the other two tables in terms of the many to many relationship.

**The Problem:**
I am now wondering where to store the information about which Article gets ordered how often.

**My Idea:**
I thought about storing this information in the linking table. However normally Symfony does not create an Entity for this. Therefore I think that there might be a better solution.

Does anybody have Idea where to store this information? :)

Comment: This is a very common question.  Make yourself an ArticleOrder entity with whatever additional properties you need then setup One to Many relations between it and your Article,Order entities. Don't use Doctrine's Many to Many functionality at all.

Comment: Which article gets ordered how often seems to me as if you could derive it with a query as opposed to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cerad I found out, that when there is the need for storing such extra information, a Many To Many Relationship is not the right answer.

In a case like this, it makes sense to create a further Entity like OrderArticle. This Entity is in a many to one relation with both Orders and Articles.

As also stated in the Symfonycasts Tutorial here: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-doctrine-relations/many-to-many-joins

Maybe this helps someone in the future as well. :)